# Vue 3, Pinia - child component is not updated when the store is updated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have this Pinia store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axiosClient from '@/axios'

export const useTableOrderStore = defineStore( 'tableOrders', {
    id : 'tableOrders',
    state: () => {
        return {
            tableOrders: []
        }
    },
    actions: {
        addToOrder(item, quantity)
        {
            const searchIndex = this.tableOrders.findIndex((order) => order.id == item.id);

            if(searchIndex !== -1)
            {
                this.tableOrders[searchIndex].quantity += quantity
            }
            else
            {
                item.quantity = quantity
                this.tableOrders.push(item)

            }

        }
    }
})
```

Parent component:

```
<script setup>

import {ref} from "vue"
import {useTableOrderStore} from "@/store/tableOrder";
import CounterInput from "@/components/Inputs/Counter.vue"

const tableOrderStore = useTableOrderStore()

const props = defineProps(['product'])

let quantity = ref(1)

let addToOrder = (product) => {
  tableOrderStore.addToOrder(product, quantity.value)
  quantity.value = 1
}

</script>

<template>

    <div class="input-group">

      <counter-input :quantity="quantity"
                     @quantity-event="(n) => quantity = n"></counter-input>

      <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ms-1" @click="addToOrder(product)">
        Add <font-awesome-icon icon="fas fa-receipt" class="ms-2" />
      </button>

    </div>

</template>
```

Child component:

```
<script setup>

import {ref} from "vue"

let props = defineProps({
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
})

let count = ref(props.quantity)

let increase = () => {
  count.value++

  emit('quantityEvent', count.value)
}

let decrease = () =>
{
  if(count.value === 1)
    return

  count.value--

  emit('quantityEvent', count.value)
}

const emit = defineEmits(['quantityEvent'])

</script>
<template>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger btn-number"
                data-type="minus"
                @click="decrease"
        >
          <font-awesome-icon icon="fas fa-minus-circle" />
        </button>
    </span>
    <input type="text"
           name="quantity"
           :value="count"
           class="form-control input-number"
           min="1"
    >
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-success btn-number"
                data-type="plus"
                @click="increase"
        >
            <font-awesome-icon icon="fas fa-plus-circle" />
        </button>
    </span>
</template>
```

The first time method **addToOrder** is fired, the product is correctly added and child product renders is.
The first issue here is that the quantity is set to 1, but it is not set in the child component.
The second problem is with the quantity - first **addToOrder** is ok, and quantity is shown correctly, but if new quantity is added the Pinia store is updated, but it is not reflected in the component. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you run into an vuejs caveat.

```
 this.tableOrders[searchIndex].quantity += quantity
```

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
> `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue` When you modify the length of the
> array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

You directly set an item.

Instead, you could use `.splice()` to replace your item:

```
let newItem = {
   ...this.tableOrders[searchIndex],
   quantity: this.tableOrders[searchIndex].quantity + quantity
};

//replace old item with new
this.tableOrders.splice(searchIndex, 1, newItem)
```

Here are the mutation methods that triggers an update:

```
push()
pop()
shift()
unshift()
splice()
sort()
reverse()
```

The first time you use `addToOrders` works because you used `.push()` witch is one of the mutations that triggers the re-render.

Answer (score 0):

First issue, i dont know how props.quantity is not set in the child component. Try console props.quantity right after you defined props if it displayed the result as you want then try to console it inside watch method. If props.quantity has changed but your child component is not update then your child component somehow not updated. You can try to force update it and here's how: https://medium.com/emblatech/ways-to-force-vue-to-re-render-a-component-df866fbacf47 (Using the key changing technique)

Second issue, i think this one @quantity-event="(n) => quantity = n" should be @quantity-event="(n) => { quantity = n }"